# on div click change its inside html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Brief Description:** I have a `div` which has Google Maps iframe in  it. I want to change the inside iframe completely when I click this div. I am trying to achieve the same with the following code but it is not working.

Where am I going wrong?

Home.html

```
<div class="sim-row-edit-maps">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2598.0908429283936!2d75.5727857336016!3d31.318772374331786!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x391a5af808690f0f%3A0xc7b0e76486fbe177!2sSapphire+IT+Solutions+Pvt+Ltd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1536835928546" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(".sim-row-edit-maps").click(function(){
  alert("maps clicked");
  $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/drOnSwo1Ob0');
});
```

My code is changing the `scr` whereas I want to change entire `iframe`tag to

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d38490.03849859351!2d75.57911957607793!3d31.314034161618853!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x391a5af2e467dd43%3A0x19b51499bc01fdc3!2sTagore+Hospital+%26+Heart+Care+Centre+Private+Limited!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1536836365464" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Why are you're changing the `src` to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/drOnSwo1Ob0` when you actually want a google maps URL? Also, the `src` is the only thing that's different, so replacing the entire element is unnecessary.

Comment: It works if you ensure that you are clicking the div and not the contents of the iframe. Click the red area in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/p8ywr6zg/1/

Comment: @Turnip The issue is that OP is replacing the src with a youtube URL instead of the one they actually want. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/mubezk31/

Comment: @ChrisG OPs code clearly show them changing from a map to a youtube video. Thats kind of irrelevant though. The problem is that clicking within the map will not trigger the click event.

Comment: @Turnip near the end of the question, OP posted the replacement iframe which clearly uses a different google maps URL. Since the OP's code showed the youtube video perfectly fine, it's a safe assumption that "doesn't work" means "I want the other map, not the video", but I could of course be wrong about that. Thinking about it, it's even less clear to me now what the OP's actual issue is

Comment: The URL is irrelevant. As I said before _"The problem is that clicking within the map will not trigger the click event"_

Comment: @Turnip That's your assumption, I guess? I'm not seeing the OP stating this. What I *do* see is the yellow box, which seems to describe a completely different problem (and given that the iframe is only 600px wide, there's lots of space next to it to click unless the window is less wide than that)

Comment: @Turnip And there's the OP's first comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52312413/5734311), suggesting it was indeed about the URL

Comment: I'm not sure why you are directing these comments at me instead of just asking OP for clarification?

Answer (score 4):

you can replace the entire tag like this:

```
$(this).find('iframe').replaceWith(`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d38490.03849859351!2d75.57911957607793!3d31.314034161618853!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x391a5af2e467dd43%3A0x19b51499bc01fdc3!2sTagore+Hospital+%26+Heart+Care+Centre+Private+Limited!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1536836365464" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`);
```

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Like I stated in my comment, while this solves the question of how to replace the iframe with another iframe, it completely ignores the actual issue, probably due to the fact that OP is asking the wrong question.

Comment: @ChrisG yes I agree changing the src attribute should be sufficient. My solution was quite literally an answer to how the question was phrased. Doing something like `$(this).find('iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d38490.03849859351!2d75.57911957607793!3d31.314034161618853!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x391a5af2e467dd43%3A0x19b51499bc01fdc3!2sTagore+Hospital+%26+Heart+Care+Centre+Private+Limited!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1536836365464');` would make more sense

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because of "X-Frame-Origin" option, which you can study in detail on [X-Frame-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) and use appropriate setting for you.If you want you can see the x-frame-origin error on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMKbGP).

HTML

```
<div class="sim-row-edit-maps"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2598.0908429283936!2d75.5727857336016!3d31.318772374331786!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x391a5af808690f0f%3A0xc7b0e76486fbe177!2sSapphire+IT+Solutions+Pvt+Ltd!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1536835928546" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

css

```
iframe{  pointer-events:none;}
```

code

```
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.sim-row-edit-maps');
appDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
  appDiv.querySelector('iframe').src = 'https://www.youtube.com';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

hi you can do something like this :

```
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.sim-row-edit-maps');
appDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
  appDiv.querySelector('iframe').src = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d38490.03849859351!2d75.57911957607793!3d31.314034161618853!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x391a5af2e467dd43%3A0x19b51499bc01fdc3!2sTagore+Hospital+%26+Heart+Care+Centre+Private+Limited!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1536836365464';
});
```

Just be sure, your `.sim-row-edit-maps` have padding in order to really fire your click event.

[live Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3sjhcn?file=index.ts)

Comment: You have missed the point completely. The issue is the wrong replacement URL, not the method that replaces it.

Comment: @ChrisG i am not sure to understand your point. Is maybe miss understood from my side, but goal is to replace iframe url on click. Is what my code do and can be easily check on the live version.

Comment: You have not in any way even tried to address the OP's problem, all you have done is replace jQuery code with Vanilla JS.

Comment: @ChrisG i have not understand the original issue who are not replace map iframe to youtube iframe but replace map iframe to another map iframe. Please accept my sincere apology for this huge mistake. I will update my answer right now.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="main-container">
    <iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$(".main-container iframe").attr("src","www.yahoo.com");
</script>
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.